# Mediaelement.js is showing two players

Tags: html, wordpress, mediaelement.js

I'm currently trying to use the mediaelement.js plugin for wordpress.

Wordpress 3.3.1

Mediaelement.js 2.5.0

However, whenever I view it, in Firefox, Chrome, Safari... it always shows two players. One of them is nonfunctional, and the other says "loading" until you click play, and then it starts (probably due to preloading off on that issue). I've tried disabling all my other plugins in wordpress, as well as extensions/plugins in my browsers that could interfere. I have the same problem regardless of whether it is audio or video. I have tried using the both the script and the shortcodes, and both create this result.

I've provided pictures in this directory:
http://sharebox.sunnysidesound.com

Answer (score 0):

You've got a plugin that's running wpautop (automatically adding <p> tags) to the post content. There's a few things you can do about this, like installing another plugin where you can turn off wpautop.

If you don't have control over what anyone else is doing, you can add something like this to your own plugin:

```
if (!function_exists('audio_object_paragraph_fix')) {
    function audio_object_paragraph_fix($content) {
        if (strpos($content, '<audio') === false) return $content;
        $content = preg_replace('/<\/p>\s*<p>\s*<object/', '<object', $content);
        return $content;
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'audio_object_paragraph_fix', 1000);
}
```